# Does SCP will clash with FTP?

Tags: ftp, scp

Recently I got some VPS and found a problem.

The VPS which can use SCP to transport can't transport with FTP.

And the VPS which can use FTP to transport can't transport with SCP.

So, is there are some clash between SCP and FTP?

And, can SFTP replace them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCP and FTP are entirely different protocols. There's nothing inherent in either that would preclude the use of the other.